# Ant -f<buildfile> not working but -file<buildfile> works

Tags: java, ant

Has anyone else seen ANT refuse to honour the -f option but happily work with the -file option.

```
ant -f cms.xml etc etc - gives the response: build.xml does not exist!

ant -file cms.xml etc etc - : works
```

This is ANT 1.8.1 with IBM JRE 1.6. Certainly the first time I've ever seen such behaviour. The -f option was working with one target but not with another. Each target was calling a different custom task.

Can the setting of properties in each custom task upset the -f option?

I would appreciate any thoughts, Stuart.

Comment: Have you run it in debug mode?

Comment: No. :-) -debug I will try that next. Ant may tell me what its thinking about the buildfile etc.

Comment: any aliases upsetting the standard meaning of "-f"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](http://ant.apache.org/srcdownload.cgi), I can't see how this is possible as `-f` and `-file` are treated in exactly the same way.

```
else if (arg.equals("-buildfile") || arg.equals("-file")
       || arg.equals("-f")) {
     i = handleArgBuildFile(args, i);
}
```

I'd encourage you to look at the [source](http://ant.apache.org/srcdownload.cgi) too.

Comment: I cant argue with that. :-) The source code rules. I was very surpirsed to see this behaviour (early-ish ant adopter in 2001) so I've seen a few ant scripts. We were also passing in a -Dfile=blah blah property as well but I would not expect these two to get mixed up. I'll go back to the scripts.

Comment: Well we have now run with -debug and got

Comment: C:\Main_Content_updater>ant -debug -f cms.xml delete
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\tools.jar
Apache Ant version 1.8.1 compiled on April 30 2010
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

Comment: However it all works on my machine. This other guy is using JRE instead of JDK - which is maybe causing ANT to fail - but Id be surprised.

Comment: Got it. Well we know what to blame. If you use the JRE that comes with IBM websphere 7 then it fails. Switch to proper Sun JRE and all is good.

Comment: Is that the problem was due to cut and pasting between VDI sessions. Cutting the command from client VDI into notepad session on the server VDI and then trying to use that command in a CMD prompt. Although the command looked good in notepad and the CMD prompt there were corrupted characters. Lesson learnt about cut and pasting between VDI sessions.